# Javascript How to scroll down window to make newly added comment visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

when I'm on the page and adding a new comment, sometimes it's not visible.
I would like the user to see the whole comment not just piece of it.
Is it possible to scroll window after executing a method that adds new comment?
I tried window.scroll, window.scrollBy but they did not work at all.
Here you can see how it looks now and where is the scrollbar:
[image: As is now]

[image: To be]

[image: Scrollbar]

The first comment on top of the list is the newly added element but last of the array

Comment: try [scollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: Tried but does not work :(